# Scoping rules for variable and functions in contained subroutines

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I have a problem understanding why a variable (`i`) declared in a subroutine is seen in a contained subroutine, but that this is not true for a function (`fie`) which results in a compilation error. I searched for an answer and also tried to see if I could find something in the Fortran 95 standard but in vain.

I wrote a small example program:

```
program pgm
  call a
end

subroutine a
  implicit none
  integer :: i
  double precision :: fie

  i = 7
  call b
  !write(*,*) fie(9)

contains
  subroutine b
    double precision :: x
    !double precision :: fie

    x = i
    x = x + fie(i)
    write(*,*) x
  end subroutine
end subroutine


double precision function fie(ii)
  implicit none
  integer, intent(in) :: ii

  fie = ii
end function
```

When compiling this with gfortran under cygwin (gfortran 5.4.0) I get the following error message:

```
$ gfortran aa.f90
aa.f90:20:15:

     x = x + fie(i)
               1
Error: ‘fie’ at (1) is not a function
```

When enabling either of the commented lines the program compiles and runs correctly.

I saw a similar error message when using the Intel compiler (Intel Fortran 12.1.7.367, indeed quite old).

It looks like `fie` has to be made available either in the contained routine or has to be used in the encompassing subroutine, but as said I could not find an answer on the net or in the Fortran 95 standard (or maybe I didn't look for the right words).

Any explanation?

Comment: It is known to me that it would be better to use a module, but it is part of an existing code base where parts are extended (by others).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest fix is to use

```
double precision, external :: fie
```

the external attribute (also can be specified by the `external` statement) says: this is a procedure, I am not declaring a local variable.

For the declaration without the `external` to be interpreted as a function declaration the function reference must be present within the function body. Internal functions don't count. And therefore the compiler created a local double precision variable called `fie`.

Thank's to IanH for the relevant standard rule (from Fortran 2008 (16.5.1.4p5), but Fortran 95 will have an equivalent):

> If an **external or dummy procedure with an implicit interface is
>   accessed via host association, then it shall have the EXTERNAL
>   attribute in the host scoping unit**; if it is invoked as a function in
>   the inner scoping unit, its type and type parameters shall be
>   established in the host scoping unit. The type and type parameters of
>   a function with the EXTERNAL attribute are established in a scoping
>   unit if that scoping unit explicitly declares them, invokes the
>   function, accesses the function from a module, or accesses the
>   function from its host where its type and type parameters are
>   established.

Of course explicit interfaces (best using modules) are much better than external functions.

Comment: I forgot about the `external` possibility In the Fortran95 standard the paragraph "14.6.1.3 Host association" exists but is less clear, to me, in this respect.