# Segmentation fault when passing internal function as argument

Tags: fortran, gfortran, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have some code that passes an internal function of the main program as an argument to a function: when the function that been passed is eventually called it causes a segmentation fault. This only occurs when I use Windows Subsystem for Linux (I'm using Ubuntu 16 on WSL); running on native Linux or Mac machines this does not occur.

A minimal example that crashes:

```
module test1

implicit none

contains

subroutine x(ff,y)

    interface 
        real function ff(y)
            real, intent(in) :: y
        end function ff
    end interface
    real, intent(in) :: y
    integer z

    z=ff(y)

end subroutine x

end module test1

program tester
use test1
implicit none

call x(f,1.0)

contains

real function f(y)
    real, intent(in) :: y

    write(*,*) y
    f=y*y
end function f

end program tester
```

Compiled with:

```
 gfortran-7 -ggdb test_fun_passing.f90 -o test
```

The backtrace, gdb output:

```
(gdb) bt                                                                                             
#0  0x00007ffffffde320 in ?? ()                                                                         
#1  0x0000000000400734 in test1::x (ff=0x7ffffffde320, y=1) at test_fun_passing.f90:17                  
#2  0x0000000000400829 in tester () at test_fun_passing.f90:31                                          
#3  0x0000000000400860 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7ffffffde64f) at test_fun_passing.f90:27                 
#4  0x00007ffffec70830 in __libc_start_main (main=0x40082c <main>, argc=1, argv=0x7ffffffde448,             init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7ffffffde438)        at ../csu/libc-start.c:291                                                                         

#5  0x0000000000400669 in _start ()
```

This one does work (moving `f` into its own module but still passing as an argument) so it's something about `f` being contained in the program.

```
module test1

implicit none

contains

subroutine x(ff,y)

    interface 
        real function ff(y)
            real, intent(in) :: y
        end function ff
    end interface
    real, intent(in) :: y
    integer z

    z=ff(y)

end subroutine x

end module test1

module test2

implicit none

contains

real function f(y)
    real, intent(in) :: y

    write(*,*) y
    f=y*y
end function f

end module test2

program tester
use test1
use test2
implicit none

call x(f,1.0)

end program tester


gfortran-7 -ggdb test_fun_passing.f90 -o test && ./test                                                                                              
1.00000000
```

Is passing `f` in this way valid Fortran, or have I been relaying on some non-standard feature on native Linux?

Comment: Maybe some pointers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40696534/scoping-rules-for-variable-and-functions-in-contained-subroutines?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa and google search "scope of contained functions fortran"

Comment: An internal procedure (such as the `f` contained in the main program) is allowed to be an actual argument under Fortran 2008 and this is implemented in gfortran 7.  There is something else happening, then.

Comment: Before I gave up on WSL, I was building gcc/g++/gfortran (bootstrapped by the WSL gcc) in order to have a current version. Even so, there were too many problems with WSL, so I'm back to cygwin for gfortran on Windows.

Comment: I did try the latest svn version of gfortran built from source on WSL, and its still a problem. Also tried ifort 18 on native linux and this test passes, so seems to to be a WSL issue.

Comment: still a problem as of Nov 2020. See this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65066837/gnu-fortran-compiler-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-segmentation-fault-with-pa?noredirect=1#comment115034921_65066837

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I'm running into this:

https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3083 and https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/286

WSL has a non-executable stack. Running:

```
excestack -c test
```

on native linux, to remove the execstack from the binary, triggers the same error message as I have on WSL. Clearing/setting the execstack (with -c/-s)  on WSL does nothing. From the github bug report it seems its unlikely to be fixed.

Edit:

It seems moving to WSL version 2 fixes this issue

Comment: Yes, internal functions are typically passed using trampolines so executable stack is necessary.